# APache Jena write Instance to JSON-LD

Tags: java, parsing, jena, json-ld

I want to parse parts of an ontology with Apache Jena to JSON-LD. But I can only find ways to write the whole model to JSON-LD with the functions

```
    OntModel model;
    model.write(System.out, "JSON-LD");
```

or

```
    DFDataMgr.write(System.out, model, RDFFormat.JSONLD_PRETTY);
```

But I want to parse only an individual (and it's dataproperties) which is linked to a model.
Anybody got suggestions?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? It looks like the only option is to create a copy of the entire model and remove what you don't need ... there must be a better way.